# Proof of poisson distribution as a limiting case of the negative binomial distribution, using the MGF

Tags: poisson-distribution, moment-generating-function

This question is very similar to one that has previously been [answered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236728/negative-binomial-mgf-converges-to-poisson-mgf/353672?newreg=226f01b8d3464e43997f14434142d8e0), but with a different parameterization of the MGF.

The question is as follows: Show that the negative binomial distribution, $NB(n,\frac{\lambda}{n+\lambda}$), converges to the Poisson distribution, $Po(\lambda)$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

The MGF of the negative binomial is defined as $m(t)=(\frac{1-p}{1-pe^t})^k$.

Hint: the MGF for $Po(\lambda)=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$ and $lim \space n\rightarrow \infty \space \space  (1+\frac{\alpha}{n})^{-n}=e^{-\alpha}$.

Given the information given in the previous answer, this might be very easy. But as it happens, I'm not very good at math and would highly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Related posts:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118220/poisson-as-a-limiting-case-of-negative-binomial, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236728/negative-binomial-mgf-converges-to-poisson-mgf,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221828/relationship-between-poisson-binomial-negative-binomial-distributions-and-norm